# Not able to work on face detection of OpenCV in python

Tags: python, opencv, artificial-intelligence, conv-neural-network, dlib

I am currently learning Image detection using CNN etc. I found out a good article [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/a-guide-to-face-detection-in-python-3eab0f6b9fc1) which explain the face detection steps using OpenCV. I followed each and every steps. But I am really stuck since hours when trying to test a single sample image. Below is the code I used in google Colab:

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import dlib
import os
from imutils import face_utils
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX

cascPath=r'C:\Users\randomUser\Desktop\haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml'
eyePath = r'C:\Users\randomUser\Desktop\haarcascade_eye.xml'
smilePath = r'C:\Users\randomUser\Desktop\haarcascade_smile.xml'
faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cascPath)
eyeCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(eyePath)
smileCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(smilePath)

# even if I use the below path, I am still getting the error.
path = r'C:\Users\randomUser\Desktop\imagedata.jpeg'
gray = cv2.imread('imagedata.jpeg')
plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
plt.imshow(gray, cmap='gray')
plt.show()
```

I have downloaded all the default files as mentioned above in my directory location along with the test image **imagedata**

However, when I am running the first few steps, I am getting the below error :(

I have tried giving physical path but I don't understand what am I missing.

[image]

I ran through different articles that explain the nature of the error, but none of them helped so I thought of asking here directly.

Comment: Hi, the only thing that comes to me right now is to try removing ```cmap='gray'``` from ```plt.imshow()```. I understand that ```png``` and ```jpg``` images handle array of integers as data images in ```TIFF``` format hanldles floats.

Comment: already tried that...but not working :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue that I was facing was because of the google drive path. After researching and using the Image path, I found out that when using colab, and mounting the google drive, even if you give the absolute path, it will add **/content** at the beginning of the path. Just because of this the path was not correct.

Answer (score 0):

You should:

```
print( gray.shape )
```

after you read it. Because most likely you're reading a non-existent file that renders all code below that moot.

Comment: that I what I am stuck into. I have provided the physical location of the file as per screen shot. and when I go to that path, I find the image there. but still I am not able to figure out how it is not loading the image. am i giving the incorrect path?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the error:

```py
# This is what you have
path = r'C:\Users\randomUser\Desktop\imagedata.jpeg'
gray = cv2.imread('imagedata.jpeg')

# This is what you should have
path = r'C:\Users\randomUser\Desktop\imagedata.jpeg'
gray = cv2.imread(path) # <-- you weren't using the path of the image
```

Opening the image with PIL?

```py
from PIL import Image

path = r'C:\Users\randomUser\Desktop\imagedata.jpeg'
gray = Image.open(path).convert("L") # L to open the image in gray scale
```

Comment: that also wont work... I have added the path and also the image file name...none of that worked :(

Comment: Oh no, I thought that was the problem :(

Comment: What about trying to open the image with another package like PIL?